# Can someone create tags for MOF (Managed Object Format) and CIM (Common Information Model)?

Tags: discussion

I've [posted a question just now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296994/is-it-possible-to-have-an-optional-key-property-in-a-dsc-resource) that is very specific to [the technologies cited in the title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa823192(v=vs.85).aspx), and I couldn't find corresponding tags for them in StackOverflow.

I noticed [there is already a `mof` tag that stands for 'Meta Object Facility'](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mof/info) and a [`cim` tag for 'Customer Information manager'](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cim/info), so I'm not sure how the best practices for creating tags work when naming things with the same acronym.

Comment: How many questions containing these two technologies already exist on the site?

Comment: @Compass I'm not sure actually. I didn't think about that when I asked this, as I did not know there was some minimum amount of questions about a subject needed before creating the tag. By quickly searching for `mof files` though, I found quite a bunch of them, and some were even using these tags I mentioned wrongly, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398617/provide-conditions-for-parameters-in-mof-file) and also [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918888/is-there-a-specification-for-mof-comment-delimiters)

Comment: @Compass, some of the questions that are currently tagged with `dsc` actually pertain more with the MOF format and CIM; though `dsc` is still an appropriate tag for them I think because they were using these with DSC.